# VS2017 Item Template not showing up in Xamarin project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I created a new VS2017 project template because the C# 'Class' template for Xamarin.Android adds way too much usings for my tastes. Here's the `.vstemplate` file:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>Class.cs</DefaultName>
    <Name>Class</Name>
    <Description>An unfancy C# class.</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Class.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

I can't figure out why, but this item template won't show up in my Xamarin.Android project. However, the template does show up when I create a new .NET Core/Framework project and click **Add > New Item**.

Any clue what's causing this? I've been staring at MSDN/StackOverflow questions for half an hour but none of them seem to help with this.

I'm using the latest stable build of VS2017, which I think is 15.2.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `<AppliesTo/>` element. See [AppliesTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/extensibility/appliesto-element-visual-studio-templates)

Using your template you would do:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>Class.cs</DefaultName>
    <Name>Class</Name>
    <Description>An unfancy C# class.</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <AppliesTo>CSharp</AppliesTo>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Class.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately, this causes it *not* to show up in places it was previously showing up, like in .NET Standard libraries. What are all possible values of `AppliesTo`? I want to try using all of them and see where that gets me.

Comment: Doing as I showed in the answer solved the problem for me in the tests I did. But I was only trying to get it to work for .NET Standard (Portable) projects. With the old project file format. Documentation doesn't seem to cover possible values. But I did find this https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/overview/about_project_capabilities.md and this https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/overview/project_capabilities.md They might help you track down some values to use.